# C++11 static_assert and template instantiation

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, should the operation of static_assert within a template depend on whether that template has been instantiated or not? For example, with the following code

```
template <int I>
void sa() { static_assert(0,"Hello."); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { return 0; }
```

GCC 4.5.0 will fail the assertion, and produce the "Hello." message.
The Digital Mars Compiler version 8.42n on the other hand, gives no message.

Comment: The compiler is expected to build an AST for the template when it sees it. I've tested this with gcc 4.5 myself, and if anything in the static_assert expression depends on the template argument, you no longer get an error message. I'm not sure what the correct behavior is either. It might be that both are acceptable.

Comment: Weird. What happens when you make the assertion depend on `I`? For example, try asserting `sizeof I == 0` which should always be `false`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

GCC is correct and the other compiler is correct too. Refer to 14.6p8 in the spec

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition, and that template is not instantiated, the template deﬁnition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Therefor, a compiler is free to reject the following

```
template<typename T>
void f() {
  static_assert(0, "may trigger immediately!");
  static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "may trigger immediately!");
}
```

If you want to go safe, you have to arrange it so the compiler cannot know until instantiation whether the boolean expression will be true or false. For example, get the value by `getvalue<T>::value`, with `getvalue` being a class template (one could specialize it, so the compiler cannot possibly know the boolean value already).

Comment: Perhaps `std::is_same_v<T,T>` will be the most convenient when it appears.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that the compiler is well within it's rights to expand any static assertions that are not dependent on template parameters without needing an instantiation- but I don't believe this is required. Remember also that different draft Standards may have different rules about when this may occur.

Comment: Except for one small problem. Template specializations can make code dependent on template arguments in non-obvious ways because it may arrange for cases in which that code is never expanded. Since a template specialization can occur well after a template definition, this means the compiler cannot give an error for the template definition even if it can determine that the static_assert would always fail.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Except when the compiler is finished with the translation unit, it knows whether or not to trigger the assert, because it's seen all the specializations.

Comment: Well, that might be the case, and would be a good argument if that's what gcc 4.5 is doing, but it isn't. I added a specialization that did not have the `static_assert`, and the `static_assert` still triggered.

Comment: @Omnifarious: That's because the `static_assert` is not dependent on the template parameter in any way, making it impossible for you to remove the fact that it failed.

Answer (score 6):

The C++0x draft ([N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)) says in 14.6p8:

> "If no valid specialization can be
>   generated for a template deﬁnition,
>   and that template is not instantiated,
>   the template deﬁnition is ill-formed,
>   no diagnostic required."

The same words appear in the C++03 standard.

In the case of the example from the question, no valid instantiation can be made for this template, so the quoted wording applies.

Since no diagnostic is required, the compiler may compile the program if the template is not instantiated. Of course, if it is instantiated then the program is ill-formed, with a diagnostic required.

Comment: I think the quotation supports what I said.

Comment: No diagnostic is **required**, but the program is still ill-formed, so the compiler **may** refuse to compile it. Both gcc and Digital Mars exhibit conforming behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

I used a helper function to make the false dependent on the template parameter:

```
template<typename T> 
bool dependentFalse<T>()
{
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
Foo foo()
{
    static_assert(dependentFalse<T>(), "this template shouldn't be instantiated");
}
```

Comment: I don't know what this is, but it surely does't compile.

Comment: @cubuspl42 it's missing constexpr for the dependentFalse template. (remember also to define a Foo type and such if you're just going to copy/paste this and compile)

Answer (score 4):

This is `14.6.2` section in C++ standard.

Your `static_assert` is related to support **binding nondependent names when initially parsing a template**. The Digital Mars Compiler does not currently support binding nondependent names. GCC 4.5.0 does support binding nondependent names.

If your expression does not depend on the template parameters then such expression is known when initially parsing a template. Compiler must show the error message. GCC 4.5.0 does it.

Replace your `0` in `static_assert` with `I*I < 0`, for expample and you get dependent name. Error message will appear for the case of uninstantiated template only.

Comment: Anthony and Johannes quote "no diagnostic required" from the C++0x standard at 14.6.8 in [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)