# Compile time check if a function is used/unused c++

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming, code-generation

I'd like to check during compile time if some function of *some class* is used/not used, and accordingly fail/pass the compilation process.

For example if function `F1` is called somewhere in the code I want the compilation to succeed, and if function `F2` is called I want it to fail.

Any ideas on how to do that, with usage of preprocessor, templates or any other c++ metaprogramming technique?

Comment: "If F1 is called it shall succeed" is a strange requirement. Do you mean: "If F1 is *not* called it shall fail to compile"?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ahm, fair enough, I retract my comment.

Comment: Another problem: "At compile-time..." - but the function might be used in a different translation unit!

Comment: rename the function, the linker will tell you if its used.

Comment: Should be checked at compile-time? It could be easily checked at runtime

Comment: There is no way for the *compiler* to tell if an external function is called or not, only functions defined in the translation unit currently being compiled. I haven't found any suitable command line option for that (the `-Wunused-function` only warns about non-inline `static` functions). I haven't seen anything appropriate in among the linker flags either. You might have to make the linker create a map file, and if it contains that information then parse that file and issue a build-process error.

Comment: Can you tell us more about *why* you want that? I'm pretty sure there is a better solution for the *actual* problem.

Comment: I didn't say the code was coming from some external translation unit. But this could be quite a lot of code to track changes and make sure no one is doing anything _italic_ bad_italic_  with it.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this with a c++11 compiler provided you are willing to modify F2 to include a static_assert in the function body and add a dummy template to the signature:

```
#include <type_traits>

void F1(int) {    
}

template <typename T = float>
void F2(int) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Don't call F2!");
}

int main() {
 F1(1);  
 F2(2);  // Remove this call to compile
}
```

If there are no callers of F2, [the code will compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dece4b21df18a95). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5246686/425495) for why we need the template trickery and can't simply insert a `static_assert(false, "");`

Comment: ... and remove the old implementation of `F2`.

Comment: There is no need to remove the old implementation, just modify the existing one.

Comment: ... and move it to the header. If you don't, you'll get errors of undefined template at call site (instead of the `static_assert` firing). Still good enough for "compile-time error if `F2` is called", I guess.

Comment: Agreed; I forgot to take that into account in my example. It's probably less hassle to just rename the function per the comment from @mah to achieve the compile-time error.

Comment: Looks like a good direction... How about making this a bit more complicated :-)

Say I have a set of functions F1...Fn and a set of classes C1...Cm Is there a way for me to make the code compile/not compile under a known rule set where for each class Ci it is allowed to call only a subset of the functions F1..Fn (different subset for each class.


Also making things even more complicated, what if I want soundness. Meaning - making sure that some function *is* called from somewhere.

Comment: the drawback is that turning `F2(int)` into a template affects overload resolution. Suddenly `F2(somthing)` might call a different `F2`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very templatey solution, but instead you can rely on compiler's deprecated attribute that will generate warning if a function is used anywhere.

In case of MSVC you use [__declspec(deprecated)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx%20%22__declspec(deprecated)%22%20attribute.) attribute:

```
__declspec(deprecated("Don't use this")) void foo();
```

G++:

```
void foo() __attribute__((deprecated));
```

If you have "treat warnings as errors" compile option on (which you generally should) you'll get your desired behaviour.

```
int main() 
{
    foo(); // error C4966: 'foo': Don't use this
    return 0;
}
```