# Template dependent false

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer

I have a class template which can't be used directly, only specializations are allowed. And I want to use `static_assert` to show meaningful error message. 
I can't just type `static_assert(false, "error");` since `false` isn't value dependent and compiler may show error message even if the template is never used.

My solution:

```
template<class>
struct AlwaysFalse : std::false_type{};

#define DEPENDENT_FALSE(arg) AlwaysFalse<decltype(sizeof(arg))>::value

template<class T>
struct Foo{
    static_assert(DEPENDENT_FALSE(T), "You must use specialization!");
};

template<int i>
struct Bar{
    static_assert(DEPENDENT_FALSE(i), "You must use specialization!");
};
```

But I'm not sure about realization `DEPENDENT_FALSE`. Because MSVC [doesn't](http://rextester.com/OCOBN40973) treat `sizeof(arg)` as template dependent expression([unlike GCC](http://rextester.com/TEBIO81232)), but `decltype(sizeof(arg))` [is fine](http://rextester.com/OGJFG98733).

Can somebody explain this behavior in terms of standard? Is it portable?

Comment: Same ways you do for a class: declare its =default constructor protected, or some virtual methods pure, or a virtual destructor protected. Yes, struct can have constructors and virtual methods, though they stop you using proper c-style aggregate initialisation. The constructor is cheep. The virtual methods have a cost if you don't otherwise want virtuals.

Comment: @Gem Taylor What on earth are you babeling about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
#define DEPENDENT_FALSE(arg) AlwaysFalse<decltype(sizeof(arg))>::value
```

fails to actually be *dependent*. `decltype(sizeof(arg))` is always `size_t`, it doesn't actually depend on `arg` in any way (more broadly, here is a [list of expressions](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#expr-4) that are never type-dependent). Since it's not dependent, a compiler is perfectly able to see that `DEPENDENT_FALSE(T)` is `false` and just trigger that `static_assert`.

What you want is just:

```
#define DEPENDENT_FALSE(arg) AlwaysFalse<decltype(arg)>::value
```

That is, drop the `sizeof`. This now *is* dependent.

---

This won't work for the `int` directly, since that again won't be dependent (`decltype(i)` is just `int`, and we need something value-dependent now). For that, you can just wrap it in an integral constant:

```
template<class T>
struct Foo{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalse<T>::value, "You must use specialization!");
};

template<int i>
struct Bar{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalse<std::integral_constant<int, i>>::value, "You must use specialization!");
};
```

Comment: I am uncertain this helps: so long as there is no instance of the primary specialization that makes the instantiation valid, isn't the program ill-formed?  Or is a function with a static assert sufficiently valid?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont There must be a valid specialization, period. The primary doesn't have to be valid.

Comment: the standard uses specialization differently than we do.  I believe each of the partial/primary/full soecializations have to have a valid instantiation.  But not certain.

Comment: I thought [I was told by you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657098/4832499) that this is in fact ill-formed NDR. Or perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30079285/4832499)?

Comment: @PasserBy Neither of those answers says that. The key is that `AlwaysFalse<T>::value` could hypothetically be specialized to be true, somewhere. But `false` and `sizeof(T) != sizeof(T)` are always `false`, neither of those depends on a template parameter.

Comment: But wouldn't it be the same if `AlwaysFalse` doesn't have any specialization that that has `true` as `value`? It is still true that no `Foo<T>` (of the primary template) is a valid specialization. At the first point where `Foo` can possibly instantiated, if no specialization of `AlwaysFalse` up to that point has `true` as `value`, either it doesn't has one which is ill-formed NDR, or there is one after the point, which is also ill-formed NDR, isn't it?

Comment: @PasserBy I could always, at some arbitrary point in the future, write `struct Troll { }; template <> struct AlwaysFalse<Troll> : true_type { }; Foo<Troll> f`. There's no "up to that point" with templates.

Comment: @PasserBy That said, it'd be great if we just had a language feature that was like `diagnostic_if_instantiated(msg);` so we wouldn't even have to worry about this.

Answer (score -1):

Solution which works on C++17. Unfortunately I have only C++11

```
template<auto>
constexpr bool dependentFalseHelper(){
    return false;
}
template<class>
constexpr bool dependentFalseHelper(){
    return false;
}

#define DEPENDENT_FALSE(arg) (dependentFalseHelper<arg>())
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the following idea:

```
template<typename T>
struct AlwaysError
{
    AlwaysError<T>()
    {
        std::cout << T::value << std::endl;
        static_assert( T::value, "You must use specialization!");
    }
};


template <typename T>
struct Foo: public AlwaysError<Foo<T>>
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct Foo<int>{};

int main()
{
    //Foo<double> d; // error message as expected
    Foo<int> i;  // specialized, compiles!
}
```

The assert message contains the text and also the type which should be specialized. In hope it helps!