# if constexpr and syntax error 'type'

Tags: c++, type-conversion, syntax-error, constexpr

I'm making function that converts ints or floats to string:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename From>
inline std::string ToStr( const From& src )
{
    constexpr bool isIntegral = std::is_integral<From>::value;
    constexpr bool isFloat = std::is_floating_point<From>::value;

    if constexpr ( isIntegral )
        return ( std::_Integral_to_string<char>( src ) );
    else if ( isFloat )
        return ( std::_Floating_to_string( "%f", src ) );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ToStr( 123 );
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I get following errors:
- syntax error 'type' on line 11 (first if)
- illegal else without matching if on line 13 (second if)

I don't know how to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: There is no `type` on the 4th line. Present your [MCVE].

Comment: Highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246049/c11-static-assert-and-template-instantiation

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but that's exactly the same code that gives exactly this errors. I was confused because as you wrote there is no `type` on that line.

Comment: you can probably declare a constexpr variable and use it in the if condition: `constexpr auto mycondition = std::is_integral<From>::value;` and use mycondition in the 'if' statement.

Comment: Have you enabled c++17 flags?

Comment: @Condzi It cannot be. For a start, you are missing several headers, and there is no `main` function. I repeat, present your [MCVE].

Comment: @max66: How do you do that?

Comment: @Serge: No, `if constexpr` is a specific C++17 feature that has a different meaning.

Comment: Now I've added whole code that you can try to compile to recreate the problem. 
@max66 I have enabled latest C++ standard.

Comment: Thankyou - now please update the line numbers, or ideally just paste the error verbatim.

Comment: What is your _exact_ compiler version?

Comment: _MSC_VER says it is 19.10

Comment: Take a screenshot of the About dialog please

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9BfuJ3n.png ( from Help->About MS VS? )

Comment: @Condzi: Okay answer updated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i see, but i do not think that this new use would do much to the optimized program. The end product in both cases, `if constexpr` and the current implementation would be the same. So, whatever works. The current one will work in c11.

Comment: @Serge `if constexpr` means the block doesnt even need to be semantically valid if the condition doesn't hold. It's different (in general). I believe the intent is to replace the mess of `enable_if` SFINAE metahackery!

Comment: (not saying it's deffo required for this particular example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running version 15.2.

Microsoft said in [a blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/) that `if constexpr` is supported in 15.3 (Preview 2).

So, try upgrading Visual Studio.

Microsoft makes it very difficult to clearly manage different versions of their software, because they want everyone to "just" upgrade to the latest all the time. Sadly that is not particularly practical in cases like this, when you need to know what is in what.